# Ubuntu via Wubi refuses to show up in boot menu

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, windows-vista, wubi

I'm in this strange situation:

I have 3 partitions, one for Vista (C), one for Windows 7 (D), and one 10GB partition (E). At least that's how my original OEM Vista partition sees them.

The primary OS that I boot into everyday is Windows 7. The situation is that for some reason it sees the Windows 7 partition (its own) as drive C, the 10GB one as (D) and the Vista one as (E).

I've successfully used the Wubi installation before on Vista, but now it simply doesn't work.

Ubuntu just does not show up in the boot menu, no matter what I try to do. I'm running out of ideas. I heard it doesn't really play well with Windows 7 either. I set it to Vista compatibility mode and that didn't work, I also tried installing it from Vista itself and that didn't work either for some reason.

Any ideas what I should try?

If anyone is about to suggest EasyBCD, please underline the command-line instructions I'm gonna need to follow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in the end was to simply do a complete install of Ubuntu, removing the need for Wubi.

I suspect I had a corrupt (or at least confused) Windows boot manager. Grub works fine and sends me to the Windows boot manager just fine -- even though I have a mysterious duplicated "Windows 7 Loader" on both partitions.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like WIndows did you in. When you originally did a Wubi install under Vista, it was installed in the "E:" drive. The Vista boot procedure was modified by WUbi to look for Ubuntu on the "E:" drive. When you installed Windows 7, it looks like it took the "C:" drive, which was originally Vista's "drive". Since the "C:" drive no longer contains Vista's boot process (now on the "E:"drive - where the Wubi boot process now resides), you no longer get the option to do a Wubi boot. Since I am not familiar with either the Vista nor the Win. 7 boot procedure (I use XP and it has a different boot procedure), I can say for 100% certainty, but this is what I suspect. If you could get Vista to be the "C:" drive, your "Wubi install" to be the "D:" drive and Win. 7 the "E:"drive, it would probably work - again, not familiar with the boot up process of Vista and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is being discussed here:

**[Wubi installer doesn't appear in boot menu on Windows 7](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/318135)**

Comment: i've read that discussion a while back and while it provides some useful information, it doesnt really solve the problem for me

Comment: then i'm at a loss, i always use BootStar for my multiboot setups, this way i ensure partitions are properly hidden from each other and nothing gets messed up, plain and simple.